# How do I check all check boxes when clicking a label in my MVC aplication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a web grid filled with 10 columns, and an n number of rows. The entire web grid is filled with check boxes (apart from the first row which contains the column names), when I click the header of a certain column I want every check box in that column to be checked (regardless if some were checked and some weren't). And when I click it while every check box is checked, I want the reverse effect (to uncheck them all if all of them were checked).

Here is what I did in javascript:

```
$('.webgrid3-table th:nth-child(5)').click(function () {
    if ($("input[name='val']").attr("checked") != "checked"){
        $("input[name='val']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});
```

What I get from this is it only checks the entire column once per page reload, I want to make it work so it will always work, and even toggle between all checked and none checked.

Here is the design of the web-grid:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertSensorsInExistingPredefineView", "PredefinedViews", FormMethod.Post))
{

@gridSensorChoose.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid3-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid3-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid3-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid3-alternating-row",//
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid3-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid3-row-style",//
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:

    gridSensorChoose.Columns(

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorID", format: @<text>  <input readonly="readonly" name="SensorID" id="SensorID" value="@item.SensorID" />  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("DeviceID", format: @<text>  <span id="DeviceID">@item.DeviceID</span>  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorType", format: @<text>  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">@item.SensorType</span>  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorName", @Html.Localize("sensorName").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span><label id="SensorName">@item.SensorName</label> </span>  </text>, style: "col2Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("VAL", format: @<text><span class="Val"> @Html.CheckBox("val") </span></text>, style:"col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("MIN", format: @<text><span class="Min"> @Html.CheckBox("min") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("AVG", format: @<text> <span class="Avg"> @Html.CheckBox("avg") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("MAX", format: @<text> <span class="Max"> @Html.CheckBox("max") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SUM", format: @<text> <span class="Sum"> @Html.CheckBox("sum") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("INT", format: @<text> <span class="Int"> @Html.CheckBox("int") </span> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false)

                                ))


<input type="submit" value="@Html.Localize("save")" formaction="/PredefinedViews/InsertSensorsInExistingPredefineView" />
}
```

This view displays the following html in the browser like so:

```
<table class="webgrid3-table">
<thead>
    <tr class="webgrid3-header">
        <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?   selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorID&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorID</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=DeviceID&amp;sortdir=ASC">DeviceID</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorType&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorType</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Sensor Name
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            VAL
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            MIN
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            AVG
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            MAX
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            SUM
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            INT
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">10</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">2</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 15cm</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">3</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 30cm</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">4</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">101</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness prvi</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">5</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">201</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Ait temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">6</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">202</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Air humidity </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">7</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">203</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Wind speed </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">8</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">204</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Wind direction </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">9</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">205</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Precipitation </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">10</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">206</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Solar radiation </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">51</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">20</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Battery </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum" style="display: none;"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorID">56</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span id="SensorType" class="SensorType">101</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness drugi</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val"> <input id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span></td>
        <td class="col1Width"><span class="Min" style="display: none;"> <input id="min" name="min" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="min" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Avg" style="display: none;"> <input id="avg" name="avg" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="avg" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Max" style="display: none;"> <input id="max" name="max" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="max" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Sum"> <input id="sum" name="sum" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="sum" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <span class="Int" style="display: none;"> <input id="int" name="int" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="int" type="hidden" value="false"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$('.webgrid3-table th:nth-child(5)').on("click",function () {
if($("input[name='val']:checkbox:checked").length < ($("input[name='val']:checkbox").length))
    $("input[name='val']:checkbox").prop("checked",true);
else
    $("input[name='val']:checkbox").prop("checked", false);    
});
```

I have not tested this one but it should work. Let me now for further help.

Comment: Oh... Use the code done in following fiddle. Its working. http://jsfiddle.net/1vp29wxq/ . Again Let me now for further help.

Comment: Thank you very much! works like a charm! :D Can you tell me my mistake and what you did?

Comment: Yeah sure Welcome.... :-) I have used "prop" function instead of "attr" . "attr" is deprecated. and gave ":checkbox" selector to let jquery knows that we only want the count of checkbox with name "val". because you have also "text" field with name "val". So count of total input was comming wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class to all the elements of the column?
That way, you will be able to select them an check or uncheck all the checkboxes of that class.

Comment: How would I add a class to `@Html.CheckBox("val")`? Keep in mind I cant change the code to `<input...` like it shows in the html because I get messed up results in the controller.

Comment: Okay, I managed to add the class, but I still get the same results as my initial problem- It only selects once.

Answer (score 0):

Put all those checkBox class name as same like below  (for Example)

```
<tr class="webgrid3-alternating-row">
    <td class="col1Width"><span class="Val">
        <input class="check" id="val" name="val" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="val" type="hidden" value="false"> </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then change your Java script code like below.

```
$('.webgrid3-table th:nth-child(5)').click(function () {
   $('.check').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: How would I add a class to `@Html.CheckBox("val")`? Keep in mind I cant change the code to `<input...` like it shows in the html because I get messed up results in the controller.

Comment: Okay, I managed to add the class, but I still get the same results as my initial problem- It only selects once.

Comment: Use html helper like this '@Html.CheckBox("val", new { @class = "check" })'.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that but it still does the all check only once. So after I successful check all after the click,  if I uncheck one or 2 or all, it will not repeat the action of checking all once I click the label.

Comment: Once the successful check happened, then uncheck some checkbox and please check your code in browser is all those checkbox have the same class name or not. And let me know one more thing are you load the table data by using any ajax function. Please answer those two question

Comment: Yes they all have the same class, the html doesnt change after I uncheck some or all of them. Yes I am loading the table data using ajax load, and all of them are loaded unchecked (as it should).

Comment: Just check with alert if the radio button click is working after you checked all checkbox and uncheck some of them. To check radio button trigger function